# How to omit acronyms with only a single occurrence in `acro`?

Tags: acro

I thought that `single = false` is the correct option for this, however, the following MWE yields unexpected results:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
    single-style = long,
    single = false
}

\DeclareAcronym{CBN}{
  short = CBN,
  long  = Central Bank of Nigeria
}

\DeclareAcronym{TOPB}{
  short = TOPB,
  long  = Theory of Planned Behaviour
}

\begin{document}

One \ac{CBN}, Two \ac{CBN}
One \ac{TOPB}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Actual result:

---

One Central Bank of Nigeria (CBN), Two CBN One Theory of Planned Behaviour (TOPB)

**Acronyms**

**CBN** Central Bank of Nigeria

**TOPB** Theory of Planned Behaviour

---

Expected result:

---

One Central Bank of Nigeria (CBN), Two CBN One Theory of Planned Behaviour

**Acronyms**

**CBN** Central Bank of Nigeria

Comment: Actually, `single = true` achieves what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right key but the wrong meaning of its truthfulness. `\acsetup{single=true}` (or simply `\acsetup{single}`) will treat acronyms with a single occurence in an exceptional fashion and give the long-form only.
Instead `\acsetup{single=false}` is the default which does not treat acronyms with a single occurence in an exceptional fashion and produces the full form on first usage regardless of whether the acronym is subsequently used again or not.